# json_encode range from array

Tags: javascript, json

Once again hit a road block..
I need to encode from my json file a range of values and everything outside of that range would be null.  Any suggestions as to how I could accomplish this?

For instance: if json value >100 then return value into new array, if json value <100 return null into same new array.

Here is my code:

```php
$url = 'http://magicseaweed.com/api/API_KEY/forecast/?spot_id=3952';
$JSON = file_get_contents($url);

$data = json_decode($JSON,true);

foreach ($data as $record) {
    $array[] = array($record['localTimestamp']*1000, $record['wind']['direction']);
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What do you mean `if json > 100`? `$JSON` is an array, it's not a single value you can compare with 100.

Comment: I mean if the values in my raw JSON file are above ore below 100 either return the value or null and put them into my array

Comment: Do you mean the value of `$record['wind']['direction']`?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I mean

Comment: Just put an `if` statement in your `foreach` loop, what's the problem?

Comment: I wasn't sure the right way to proceed.  I'll give it a shot.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a conditional expression:

```
foreach ($data as $record) {
    $val = $record['wind']['direction'];
    $array[] = array($record['localTimestamp']*1000, $val > 100 ? $val : null);
}
```

Comment: That was it!  Thanks Barmar!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe

```
if ($record['wind']['direction'] > 100)
```

??

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to add in an extra line of code in your foreach loop like:

```
foreach ($data as $record) {
    $value = array($record['localTimestamp']*1000, $record['wind']['direction']);
    if($value > 100){
        $value = NULL;
    }
    $array[] = $value;
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: You can't compare an array to 100.